# Xpath for nested Objects

Tags: object, xpath

I have to find out the Radio Button for the record having some text. I have a record table, there are more than 20 records per page. Now, I need to select the radio button associated with record having some text. Only issue is - Radio Button table is not same as Record table. i.e.
Xpath of text is:

```
html/body/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]
```

Xpath for same record Radio button is:

```
html/body/div[6]/table/tbody/tr[8]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[1]
```

I can go to other text in table using following siblings or proceeding sibling options. But, I can not move up to table where my radio button exists.

Below works fine: Individually.

```
 //tr[2]/td[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/input[@name='objectId']


 //tr/td[2]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[contains(text(),'GBANKUS')]]
```

Please help.

Comment: Will you post a minimal input html that represents your problem?

Comment: I have added the working xpath for both objects. I want to club them together. When I use xpath individually under firepath - it locates the object correctly. But that is happening for individual object. I want GBANKUS text record radio button with Single path. So that I can parametrize the text for my automation script.

Comment: you can use access the siblings with 

/preceding-sibling::td[contains(text(),'GBANKUS')]]

I hope this could help!

Comment: I did try with that. But it works only when my radio belongs to same element entry. For example: You are at C:/A/B/C/D. So you are use preceding and following siblings for each child in D. Now problem is that, My Text is in D where as my Radio button is under D:/A/B/C/D/E. So, I use the / to reach up to root and then use again / to reach to D:/A/B/C/D/E. But it is not working somehow.